# Лагает unity в пустом проекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: рендеринг в пустом проекте]

Всем доброго дня!недавно поменял ссд на ноутбуке,до этого стояло msata ssd на 32 гига и работало все прекрасно.Сейчас поменял на ssd gigabaty 260 но теперь тут фризы.Диск проверял,дрова на видеокарту есть,помогите срочно пожалуйста!

Comment: дрова на SSD надо поставить, отключить восстановление системы и удалить все точки восстановления, но выглядит как просто хреновый SSD, если я правильно понял суть этих графиков, хотя не знаю, как графика может быть связана с диском.